# Need Help Formatting with the code

Tags: php, css

Ok I have been dying on this page...the code is below...if you can visit and see that it is not formatting right...I am wanting it to format in a way that it is all in line and not jumbled up like it is...what do I change in the code below...

Where one properity is below the other...u will see when you look at the site

http://ampmproperties.com/listing-of-properties-available

```
<style>
    #para1{ text-align:center;}

    .bdr_blb{ 
        border:#000000 solid 4px;
        height:70px;
        background:#cccccc;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:14px; font-weight:700;}

    .light32{ font-size:32px;}

    .bggrey{ background:#cccccc;}

    .light18{ font-size:18px;}

    #bedroom4{
        background:#cccccc;
    }

    .heading_div{float:left;}

    .entry-content{float:left;}

    .thumnail_col ul li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none outside none;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .thumnail_col ul li img{background:none; border:none;}

</style>

?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="" role="main">
            <?php $args = array( 'category_name' => 'lease', 'orderby' => 'title' ,'order' => 'ASC' );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        if ($count==1)
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                       <td><div class="lease">
                            <div class="heading_div"><h2 class="entry-title"><strong><u>
                        <?php
                                                    echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/lease/'.$loop->post->post_name.'" target="_blank">'.$loop->post->post_title.'</a>';
                        ?>
                        </u></strong></div></h2>
                            <div class="entry-content">
                                <div class="desc">
                        <?php
                            the_content();
                        ?>
                        </div>

                        </div></div></td>
                        <?php
                        if($count==$number_of_columns)
                        {
                        echo "</tr>"; 
                        $count=0;
                        }   
                        $count++;

                        endwhile;
                    ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: this is really not the place to ask these types of questions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are floating elements in each of your lease divs. You can add the following css and it should sort things out. Although I think I would recommend entering an explicit `<br style="clear: both;" />` after each entry-content instead. Although it still looks bad. Do you really want to have float: left on heading_div and entry-content at all?

```
.lease { clear: both; }
```

Comment: I am new to coding...which is clear...so how would i enter this and where? And what would be the option to your question about the entry-content?

Comment: ok it worked./..for some reason the third post and its content is out of whack? but it is aligned now...you are awesome.

Comment: CSS is what you posted in your code block. So you could add the line of code I showed you to that. A `<br />` is a line break in html. It is like pressing return in a text editor. You can enter these to force new lines. You could add that after entry-content. You should probably read some help articles on html and css before relying on SO too much. It is really to answer programming questions as opposed  to fixing people's code because they don't know what they are doing =).

Answer (score 0):

Should something be initialising "$count" and "$number_of_columns"?  Looking at your current site, there seems to be quite a few opening/closing tags missing/in the wrong place; It may not be what is messing up the formatting, but they might help with web browser compatiblity etc...